How to check attribute using playwright?
I'm using spectrum web components to show a checkbox on a webpage. Here's what I use on the site
<sp-checkbox size="m" data-test-id="test" checked="" tabindex="0" dir="ltr"></sp-checkbox>

When sp-checkbox is not checked, I want to click on it using the click(). I do the following in playwright
  testBtn = () => this.page.getByTestId("test");

  await this.testBtn().click();

testBtn refers to the sp-checkbox above on the website.
but it clicks on the checkbox regardless of whether it's checked. I only want to click on the checkbox when it's not checked.
How can I do this using playwright?
I tried the following but it doesn’t work
await this.testBtn().check()


Please show [mcve] code, what you're showing cannot be what you're actually running (given that testBtn -- which is a bare variable and your linter should have yelled at you already -- and this.testBtn are not the same thing).

Does the spectrum checkbox have a label for it defined within the element shadowroot?

const testBtn = () => this.page.getByTestId("test");

const isChecked = await testBtn().isChecked();

if (!isChecked) {
    await testBtn().click();
}



I get the error - Error: locator.isChecked: Error: Not a checkbox or radio button

Assuming the checkbox has a label for it inside the elements shadowroot, the following will work for a spectrum checkbox that has a label of 'Medium':
import { test, expect, type Page } from "@playwright/test";

test.beforeEach(async ({ page }) => {
  await page.goto(
    "https://opensource.adobe.com/spectrum-web-components/components/checkbox/"
  );
});

test("Check spectrum checkbox if not checked", async ({ page }) => {
  const checkbox = page.getByRole("checkbox", { name: "Medium", exact: true });

  if ((await checkbox.isChecked()) === false) {
    await checkbox.check();
    await expect(checkbox).toBeChecked();
  }
});



Try using CSS pseudo-class, like so:


await page.locator('[data-test-id="test"]:not([checked=""])').click();




how can I use the testId? I want to do something like page.getByTestId("....not[checked]

This would cause the test to fail if the checkbox is checked (because no element would be found).
